Deployment and Code management strategy for multiple teams
I have a web application that is based on microservices architecture (both frontend and backend). We have four tiers: Dev, SIT, UAT, and Prod. Initially we started with only one team writing code and deploying.
Recently, the number of teams have grown to three (potentially will grow further), and we started facing the environment constraint. That is, if team A's code is on UAT, they don't want team B to deploy any changes to UAT until they get UAT sign-off to ensure stable code goes to prod. Team B, meanwhile, is held up by this at SIT. At the same time, team C can't push any code to SIT because team B wants stable SIT until they deploy to UAT. Now, team A while waiting for UAT sign off, can't merge code to Dev master because team C is using this.
This sounds very trivial problem, and I just can't figure out how to solve it (I am the Product manager) - maybe I am lacking the right terms to describe it, and this hinders my search endevours.
I am looking for advice that's not specific to tech, but rather focused on solving this problem in principle, or forming a strategy to manage it. Having multiple UAT environments will add cost, and we will eventually hit the limit again as we grow.
